# Detect key press without modifier

Tags: mac-catalyst, uikeycommand

I'd like to capture a keypress in my Catalyst app.

```
UIKeyCommand(input: "", modifierFlags: nil, action: #selector(singleShift))
```

Unfortunately modifierFlags can't be nil and NSEvent isn't supported on Catalyst. Is there a way to detect single press keys? e.g. for a keyboard app or a game?

Comment: Look at the results of [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+uikeycommand+modifierflags) for several examples of creating a UIKeyCommand with no modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The field `modifierFlags` isn't optional, so you can't pass `nil`. It is of the type `UIKeyModifierFlags` which is an `OptionSet`, so if you don't want to pass a modifier you can simply pass an empty array.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        [UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputPageUp,
                      modifierFlags: [],
                      action: #selector(pageUpPressed(_:)))]
    }
}
```